# HTTP PUT Parameter

Tags: php, rest, crud

I create a rest-webservice with the php framework "tonic".
I have a User Class and handle it with the library.
According to CRUD i use HTTP_PUT to UPDATE the User:

```
function put($request) {
    $response = new Response($request);
    $split = explode ('&',$request);
    $para = array();

    foreach($split as $i) {
        $names = explode('=',$i);
        $para[$names[0]] = $names[1];
    }
    $response->body = var_dump($para);
    return $response;
}
```

My Question is how do I access the calling parameters?

At the moment I parse it manually into an array.

Comment: PUT data in PHP is available only through stdin according to the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: I am not familiar with the tonic framework, but I just completed a REST service using the Slim framework and it supports all of the rest methods, including PUT, quite easily.  It may be worth a look.  http://www.slimframework.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will not translate a classic "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" request into $_POST / $_GET if the method is PUT (and there is no $_PUT).

So if you use this content type you have to parse the query string manually:

```
<?php
$putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");
$para    = parse_str($putdata);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php